# Body is empty, only from post in React. Postman works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, prisma, body-parser

I have a React front-end with a Prisma (Express based) Node.js back-end.

I can make Post request via postman (content type: x-www-form-urlencoded). When I try to post via my front-end however, I can not seem to get my body object to contain any data.

My React Axios post function:

```
async function acceptCreateTask() {
const createTaskFormData = new FormData();

createTaskFormData.append("title", formValue.title);
createTaskFormData.append("category", formValue.category);
createTaskFormData.append("discription", formValue.discription);

try {
  const response = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:3001/task",
    data: createTaskFormData,
    headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  }).then((res) => {
    //
  });
} catch (error) {
       //
   }  
}
```

Prisma Express function

```
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

var cors = require("cors");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//create a task
app.post("/task", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  const taskTitle = req.body.title;
  const taskCategory = req.body.category;
  const taskDiscription = req.body.discription;

  if (!req.body || !taskTitle || !taskCategory || !taskDiscription) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Title, categoy or discription is missing" });
  }

  try {
    const message = "Task created successfully";

    await prisma.task.create({
      data: {
        title: taskTitle,
        category: taskCategory,
        discription: taskDiscription,
      },
    });
    return res.json({ message });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending form data. You should use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to send URL-encoded data.

Here an example using a mirror API which just mirrors the request that was sent. You should have a look at the *Body* section.

```js
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://apichallenges.herokuapp.com/mirror/request', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      'userName': 'test@gmail.com',
      'password': 'Password!',
      'grant_type': 'password'
    })
  });
  console.log(`HTTP status code: ${response.status}`);
  console.log(await response.text());
 })();
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

By the way: It's always useful to inspect the HTTP status code for those kind of errors as this will give an indication what went wrong.

This does also work with Axios. Please see [Axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/urlencoded)

```js
(async() => {
  const data = new URLSearchParams({
    'userName': 'test@gmail.com',
    'password': 'Password!',
    'grant_type': 'password'
  });
  const response = await axios.post('https://apichallenges.herokuapp.com/mirror/request', data)
  console.log(`HTTP status code: ${response.status}`);
  console.log(response.data.messageDetails);
})();
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i will look into it! Could you explain why URLSearchaParams does work and why form-urlencoded doesn't? Why would I not want to send it via my approach?

Comment: It's simply another way to encode the data. The same way you could also send that data as JSON. But client and server have to agree on one format they want to exchange data in in order for the communication to work. If the server expects URL encoded data and you send it Form data or JSON it won't be able to decode that data. 
Compare the output of  `new URLSearchParams({ 'userName': 'test@gmail.com' }).toString()` and `JSON.stringify({ 'userName': 'test@gmail.com' })`. Both contain the same information, just encoded differently

Comment: That makes sense, can URLSearchParams be seen as the standard for formdata (for Javascript)? Or is it still mainly preference? Thanks for your help and explanations, very insightful.

Comment: `URLSearchParams` is just an API there for your convience so that you don't have to craft strings like `userName=test%40gmail.com` yourself. Also Axios and the `fetch()` API will pick up on this and set the request headers accordingly. You could do it yourself if you wanted to but there are some gotchas. Maybe this explanation of [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) will help you.